# How to run the Kick command of a bot via node.js?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I tried for a moment to make a command to kick a member, but after testing in mons discord, no message appears, and the member is not kick.

So this is for a bot discord with Node.js. I tried to remake commands via sites, and via videos (for the kick command), the editor does not give me any error, but the bot does not respond to the command in question

```
client.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
      case 'kick' :
        if(!args[1]) message.channel.send('Vous devez spécifier la personne.')

        const user = message.mentions.users.first();

        if(user){
          const member = member.guild.member(user);

          if(member){
            member.kick('Vous avez été expulsé du serveur !').then(() =>{
              message.reply('Le joueur suivant a été expulsé : ${user.tag}');
            }).catch(err =>{
              message.reply('I was unable to kick the member')
              console.log(err);
            });
          } else
            message.reply("Le membre n'est pas dans la guilde.")
          }

        }


  })
```

I would therefore, possible, know why this command does not work. Even though I think I should answer your questions. Thanks in advance for all the help !

Comment: Why dont you begin by placing console.logs at every junction of your code (so before the switch case, in each switch case, before each if statement, inside each if statement, etc... etc...) to figure out where the exact problem is. That way we can help you out better by knowing where the focus of the problem lays

Answer (score 0):

You can try using command handler you can use this [guide](https://anidiots.guide/first-bot/a-basic-command-handler)
then create a folder for commands inside that folder you can create kick.js which will be for the kick command then do this

```
let kUser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));
if(!kUser) return message.channel.send("Please mention a user to kick!")
let kReason = args.join(" ").slice(22);
if(!kReason) return message.channel.send ("Please specify some reasons for the kick")
message.guild.member(kUser).kick(kReason);
message.channel.send(`${kUser} has been kicked from the server`);
```

Remember to also check permission so you are sure they have permission before they can kick members and also you can decide to log the kick in a channel where the bot send message to after the user has been click like this

```
// this will look for logchannel so if you don't have that channel you can create or let logchannel = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === "logchannel");
logchannel.send(`${kUser} has been kicked from the server`);
```